# Adding transparent horizontal line in centre on background image

Tags: html, css

The transparent line I am looking to achieve is this:

[image]

The most closest I have got to it is this using gradient:

[image]

The css for gradient is:

```
.login {
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 20%, #aaaaaa, transparent 77%),  url("bg-image.jpg");
}
```

I am only interested in getting the same transparent line.
What should I do?

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hnf96bsw/12/

Comment: Exactly the simplest approach I was looking for.

Comment: nice to hear that it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linear-gradient as follow:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)) 0 50%/100% 50px no-repeat,
  url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle in Suresh's comment is simpler without the need of linear-gradient at all.

Comment: @Farooq i know it can be done without linear-gradient, but my purpose was to correct your gradient that you made wrong ;) ... there is a TON of approach and all depends on your needs and what you want, but you used the gradient badly and i correct it ... you can pick up what you want to work with but this answer will be useful to everyone facing the same issue with gradient, it's not only for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of one possible solution:

```css
.wrap{
  height:350px;
  width:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:center
}

div div{
  background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.35);
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this. This uses flexbox to align the white 'line' vertically in the center of the image. The transparent background of the white line is done by simply using `rgba` color.

The advantage of this method is, that the height of the white line will scale with it's content.

```css
.background-image {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=85740266a52ea733187e9775fdf8d2d5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80') no-repeat center center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}


.background-image__white-line {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.background-image__white-line__content {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="background-image__white-line">
    <div class="background-image__white-line__content">
      Whatever you want
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Simplified the css code, thanks to Termani Afif!

Comment: why complicating with all these markup ? and why a pseudo element when you can simply specify an rgba color to the background ... and i don't see the utility of  positioned element

Comment: Great question! The difference is that the approach I use is content aware instead of the fixed height that you use with the linear gradient. As far as I understood Farook wants to display a login form inside this white line. What happens when the height of the form changes (e.g. an Error Message gets displayed beneath the 'Username' input field)? With my approach the white line would change it's height accordingly so the while form fits into the white line again.

Comment: am not against the approach ... and what you said won't change the `why ?` ... you used a pseudo element to cover an area and added opacity to it to create the transparence --> this is exactly equivalent as setting an rgba background to the main element and it will behave exactly the same ... also you can get rid of all the position:relative you used ... here is you code simplified with the same behavior :  https://jsfiddle.net/k5rsgxf0/2/ ... my comment was about simplification and not about the solution or the approach

Comment: I agree. That markup is simpler and does the same thing. Just for clarification: The reason for the position: relatives were 1. the z-index property on the one element and 2. the pseudo-elements position: absolute.

Comment: i know the reason of the z-index and position relative ;) and i meant there useles when doing the simplification

Comment: I figured you knew. Just wanted to add that for future readers :)